How to Maintain Google Forms and App Script When Client Doesn't Have Google Workspace
Issue 1: Ensuring App Script Continuity and Email Deliverability
I have created a set of Google Forms integrated with Google Sheets and App Script to manage Health & Safety compliance activities for a client. The scripts send weekly and monthly reminders and follow-ups via email. Currently, I am using a free Gmail account (e.g. usefulapp@gmail.com) to run these scripts. I am concerned about the continuity of these services and the guaranteed deliverability of emails.
Can I/Should I upgrade this Gmail account to ensure that the App Script will continue to function without interruption? Or is having a developer account something else?
Is there a way to guarantee email deliverability, possibly by purchasing a domain name specifically for this project? note: not the clients actual domain
Issue 2: Google Account Requirement for Form Submission with File Uploads
The users filling out the forms need to upload files, which requires them to have a Google account. However, the organization uses Microsoft for their office suite and is reluctant to pay for 10 additional Google accounts solely for occasional form submissions.
Is there a solution that allows users to upload files without needing a Google account?
Can the file upload feature be enabled in a way that does not mandate a Google account? Each of the 10-or so users have signed up to a google account but because this is upto them to do some have mistakenly signed up to a Google Trial Workspace account not a Google web user account tied to any email address.
Context:

The forms are filled out by about 10 users a handful times a month.
Both head office staff and a third party have shared access to the Sheets for data visibility.
the forms send standard receipts and add-on receipts to HQ
The App Scripts use triggers to send a "fill in this form" email, and follow up on incomplete forms.

Or: Should I just use a completely different form solution like Airtable?
I just dont want to build this system out for another client and hit the some set of reliability issues in a few weeks.

Hi Paolo, may be you will find a solution exploring on cloud identities.
https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7319251?hl=en&sjid=11165517494671578608-SA
https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7431902?hl=en&sjid=11165517494671578608-SA

Understanding your 1st concern,
It will be better if you upgrade your Gmail account to a Google Workspace since it can potentially improve the reliability of your Apps Script and email delivery. Furthermore, Google Workspace  accounts provide extra features and support that are useful and intended for business use.
Additionally, it is also a good idea to get a domain name and set this up with Google Workspace. This will enhance the email's reputation (lessen the chance of them being marked as spam).
As for your 2nd Concern,
Unfortunately, In order to upload files to Google Forms, you need to create a Google account as the files uploaded will be stored in Google Drive.
A possible alternative solution for this, is for example, what you have mentioned Airtable or other 3rd party platform that doesn't require an account.
By doing this, ofcourse, you have to think of the consequences of moving to a new platform like rewriting your script or expense-related using a different service.
Ref/Links that may be of use to you:
Email sender guidelines
Difference between Gmail and Google Workspace

thank you.. I think it was a good solution for proof-of-concept.. I  think I will investigate Zapier/Airtable solutions for something that has less "hoops" for clients teams to jump thru, and makes easier for me to redeploy per client.
